Are dynamic types stored serially in memory or on the heap?
Given the struct below within a Solana contract using the Anchor framework, if i dynamically resize items, is there risk of overwriting the memory used in items_by_key? or do both items & items_by_key contain a reference to a heap
#[account]
pub struct ProgramAccount {
     pub cfg: AccountConfig,
     pub items: Vec<Item>,
     pub items_by_key: BTreeMap<Hash,Item>,
}


It is really danger using dynamic array like your code.
If you attempt to resize these structures dynamically without enough space allocated in the account, you risk hitting Solana's memory limits, not overwriting memory directly. Therefore, ensure to predefine the account's maximum size to avoid such issues.
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = signer,
        space = {
            let data_len = user_account.to_account_info().try_data_len().unwrap_or(0);
            if data_len == 0{
                8 + UserAccount::INIT_SIZE
            }else{
                data_len
            }
        },
        seeds = [USER_ACCOUNT_SEED, args.sol_address.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub user_account: Account<'info,UserAccount>,

